# CheckboxList not retaining it's check mark on postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Checkboxlist control in a repeater control & ASP.net C#. Whenever I check its items it gets uncheck automatically. I am also calling this method when the page is not postback as well but it is not working & gets uncheck although I get the values but clears out the checkmark. I do not want to use the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in page load re-binding the repeater then you lose the settings. So you need to only bind on first load

```
(if IsPostBack = false then databind)
```

So if you re-bind the check boxes each time, then you lose their settings. The other way is to create a array or better yet a dictionary pair list - when you check a item, ALSO save that setting in the dictionay list based on row index. Then you can re-bind on load or as you like, and in the row data bind event, you set the value of the check box based on the dict pair list you maintain (you have to save that list in viewstate or session).

So, it is MUCH less work to simply ensure that you ONLY fill + bind on first page load. If you at any time re-bind the repeater, then you lose your settings. So they will persist ad survive round trips (post-backs), but ONLY if you bind one time on first page load.

It not all that hard to build up a "list" of you made choices and then on row data bind event check + set the values from that small list of choices. But as noted, it obviously easier to just avoid re-binding. However, in the cases that you can't avoid a re-bind, then you need to write your own code to persist the choices.